# Avoiding of returnable types incompatibility for conditional generic case in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The function `getExpectedToBeSingleElement` must return the specific inheritor of `Element` when `elementTypeChecker` has been specified or basic `Element` when `elementTypeChecker` has not been specified.

```js
export function getExpectedToBeSingleElement(
  parametersObject: {
    selector: string;
    context?: Element | Document;
  }
): Element;

export function getExpectedToBeSingleElement<SpecificElement extends Element>(
  parametersObject: {
    selector: string;
    context?: Element | Document;
    elementTypeChecker: (element: Element) => element is SpecificElement;
  }
): SpecificElement;
```

In the implementation, TypeScript tells me

```
TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'SpecificElement'.   
'Element' is assignable to the constraint of type 'SpecificElement', but 'SpecificElement' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Element'.
```

while I checked that `elementTypeChecker` is `undefined` therefore type will be returned is `Element` itself, not it's inheritor:

```js
import {
  Logger,
  DOM_ElementRetrievingFailedError,
  UnexpectedEventError,
  isUndefined
} from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";


function getExpectedToBeSingleElement<SpecificElement extends Element>(
  {
    selector,
    context = document,
    elementTypeChecker
  }: {
    selector: string;
    context?: Element | Document;
    elementTypeChecker?: (element: Element) => element is SpecificElement;
  }
): SpecificElement {

  const targetElementSearchRequestMatch: Array<Element> = Array.from(context.querySelectorAll(selector));

  if (targetElementSearchRequestMatch.length === 0) {
    Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
      errorInstance: new DOM_ElementRetrievingFailedError({ selector }),
      title: UnexpectedEventError.DEFAULT_TITLE,
      occurrenceLocation: "getExpectedToBeSingleElement(parametersObject)"
    });
  }


  if (targetElementSearchRequestMatch.length > 1) {
    Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
      errorInstance: new UnexpectedEventError(
        `Contrary to expectations, ${targetElementSearchRequestMatch.length} elements has been found for the selector ` +
        `"${selector}."`
      ),
      title: UnexpectedEventError.DEFAULT_TITLE,
      occurrenceLocation: "getExpectedToBeSingleElement(parametersObject)"
    });
  }

  if (isUndefined(elementTypeChecker)) {
    // Here is the error
    // TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'SpecificElement'.
    return targetElementSearchRequestMatch[0];
  }


  const targetElement: Element = targetElementSearchRequestMatch[0];

  if (!elementTypeChecker(targetElement)) {
    Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
      errorInstance: new UnexpectedEventError(
        "The picked element subtype does match with expected one specified in 'elementTypeChecker'"
      ),
      title: UnexpectedEventError.DEFAULT_TITLE,
      occurrenceLocation: "getExpectedToBeSingleElement(parametersObject)"
    });
  }


  return targetElement;
}
```

My mistake or TypeScript bug?

Comment: Does [this](//tsplay.dev/mbGQPW) work for you? Inside an overloaded function implementation, the compiler only checks the implementation signature, not the call signatures. Your implementation signature says that even if `elementTypeChecker` is undefined, the fn return type is `SpecificElement`. But you cannot guarantee that. Of course the first call signature says the return type is just `Element` in that situation, but the compiler does not consult the call signatures, as this would be too complex (see [ms/TS#13235](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235))

Comment: If that makes sense to you and you would accept an answer explaining that, I'll write one up. If not, please let me know what is missing and maybe I can address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a TS bug, however, the source of the error that you are seeing is because of this: `SpecificElement extends Element`.
which kinda **implies there's a constraint on the type such that the returned value must either be of type `Element` or of any sub-type of `Element` and it appears you aren't considering the latter.** For type safety TypeScript kinda prevents you from doing this: `return targetElementSearchRequestMatch[0]` which is of type `Element`, which is why this section of your code fails.

```
if (isUndefined(elementTypeChecker)) {
    // Here is the error
    // TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'SpecificElement'.
    return targetElementSearchRequestMatch[0];
  }
```

To make TS happy in a way that will satisfy the returned type above, you could do something like update the returned type on the function to: `SpecificElement | Element`, i.e:

```
function getExpectedToBeSingleElement<SpecificElement extends Element>(
  {
    selector,
    context = document,
    elementTypeChecker
  }: {
    selector: string;
    context?: Element | Document;
    elementTypeChecker?: (element: Element) => element is SpecificElement;
  }
): SpecificElement | Element {
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Your explanation is perfect, but if we annotate returnable type as `SpecificElement | Element`, we'll become unable to pick `Element`'s subtypes. E. g. in `const element: HTMLDivElement = getExpectedToBeSingleElement(...)` case, it will be the error `TS2322: Type 'Element | HTMLDivElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.` in spite of `elementTypeChecker` .

Comment: I am very sorry. Your solution is working. I make another mistake with exports - the function was exported as default while declarations was not. I accepted your answer.